# How can I add buttons with proper functionalities in the top of android keypad like iPhones?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Here, I just want to know that how to add buttons in the top of keypad of android devices. They should not be custom. I just want to use this functionality of android like iPhone does. I want to open and close keypad then I want also close or open next,previous and done button

I've searched it alot on this site but I haven't get a possible solution yet.
I wish I will get now.

Thanks in advance.